# Cookie Class in laravel 4, is it illuminate\cookie\cookiejar?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

According to the API documentation provided by laravel official site 
cookie class is Illuminate\cookie\cookiejar 
So When I call a function, I call it on CookieJar class
I had two problems 
When I deleted the File Containing CookieJar 
This piece of code still works

```
$cookie = Cookie::make('name','James');
```

How it's possible if I deleted the file containing the declaration of the class

The Second one is 
The value of the cookie is always encrypted, even if i commented this line

```
$value = $this->encrypter->encrypt($value);
```

Which exist in CookieJar
is there any way to make a cookie without encryption

Both Of these Problem made me doubt that CookieJar is the same as cookie class or there is something I am missing here

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Yes the `Cookie` alias points to an instance of `Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar`. If you deleted it and it still works you may have a workbench package installed that utilizes this class and thus has it installed. Hard to say really.

Comment: I am really trying hard to figure out, but i think if it's as u say it must be something in the core .
The Working Despite Deleting also applies to Routing classes

Comment: Ah, I think this is probably falling back to the `bootstrap/compiled.php` file. I always forget about this guy. When you install Laravel it compiles all the common classes into a single file so that only a handful of files are loaded each time. You can safely delete this file as you can recompile at any time using `php artisan optimize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Find facade class

Use `echo get_class(Facade::getFacadeRoot());` to determine which class it is.

Working example: `echo get_class(Cookie::getFacadeRoot());`.

### Compiled code

As for the issue of the compiled files, you can delete `compiled.php` or run:

```
$ php artisan clear-compiled
```

to clear the compiled file. Then you can run:

```
$ php artisan optimize
```

to re-create it, if you wish.

These commands are shown in the [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json#L18) file, as they are run on install and update.

Comment: Yea buddy, it was the compiled file the reason of my story, but why it's generated ?

Comment: I believe because It improves the speed of code execution by a decent chunk. I don't know the specifics on why however.